# Visual Studio, Jasmine and Chupzpah - Automatic testing

Tags: visual-studio-2015, jasmine, chutzpah

So I have finally got my project up and running with Chutzpah and Jasmine. I have also created some tests. At the moment, everytime I write a new test, I have to debug using the context menu and selecting "Run Chupzpah with Debugger".

What I would like to know is, is there a way for Visual Studio to automatically run tests as you create them?

Comment: You can have it run them onSave by checking the "Run tests after Build" button in the Test Explorer. It is confusing but for Chutzpah after build means save

Comment: can you give me some instructions on how to do that please?

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [Chutzpah Test Explorer extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f8741f04-bae4-4900-81c7-7c9bfb9ed1fe)
2. Open Test explorer

[image: TestExplorerLaunch]

3.Check run after build

[image: RunAfterBuild]